# Assume unknown tennis players B & D in three set match. Find Relation in $p$ [Probability B wins First Set] & $q$ [Probability Match ends in two sets]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, game-theory, mathematical-modeling

**Problem**
If we assume that two completely unknown tennis players **B** and **D** are facing each other in a three set match.

- Let $p$ be the probability that B wins the first set
- Let $q$ be the probability that the match ends in two sets.

Which one of the following is true?

- $p < q$
- $p = q$
- $p > q$

**My Approach**
My thinking is to assume that the probability of a player winning a set is independent if the player has won a previous set and then calculate $q$ as

$q = P(BB)+P(DD)=p^2+(1-p)^2=2p^2-2p+1$

Hence, $$q=2p^2-2p+1$$

but this equation does not have real roots.

**Edit**

I tried the suggestion on the comments on working with a few numerical examples and constructed the following table

| $p$ | $1-p$ | $q$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.9 | 0.82 |
| 0.2 | 0.8 | 0.68 |
| 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.58 |
| 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.52 |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 0.6 | 0.4 | 0.52 |
| 0.7 | 0.3 | 0.58 |
| 0.8 | 0.2 | 0.68 |
| 0.9 | 0.1 | 0.82 |

So I guess the answer depends on the value of $p$.

Comment: Is $P=p$?  Why are you interested in the roots of that equation?

Comment: I suggest working a few numerical examples.

Comment: @lulu Yes, P=p thank you for the observation. I have also edited the question with your suggestion.